Are questions about non-LEGO brick toys on-topic?
Are questions related to megabloks and similar products on-topic?
I ask because the site is bricks.stackexchange.com, but the logo is LEGO ®

I would say:
Yes
It would be ridiculous if there existed another se site for brick building toys other than Lego, so welcome one and all.
In related news, we should change the title of the site to Brick Overflow, instead of LEGO®. This would match our domain better too.

Maybe "Lego and other bricks"?

@PaŭloEbermann Way too long

@Dori Who would we be explaining it to? I think it has a clear enough meaning "I have so many bricks they're overflowing everywhere!" even if people don't get the SO reference.

@Dori Come see this cool new site, Lego Stack Exchange! Lego Stack Exchange? That's an odd name, what does it mean? Well it's a site that's part of the Stack Exchange Q&A network that's exclusively for Lego etc. enthusiasts. Oh. So why is it called Stack Exchange? Well there was this site Stack Overflow...

A third option would be to include only lego-compatible brick systems.
(I'm not sure how useful this would be.)

With glue, everything is compatible!
